# My program doesn't quite work right

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */


string numString(int k)
{
string str;

switch (k) {
    case 0 : str ="ZERO"; break;
    case 1 : str ="ONE"; break;
    case 2 : str ="TWO"; break;
    case 3 : str ="THREE"; break;
    case 4 : str ="FOUR"; break;
    case 5 : str ="FIVE"; break;
    case 6 : str ="SIX"; break;
    case 7 : str ="SEVEN"; break;
    case 8 : str ="EIGHT"; break;
    case 9 : str ="NINE"; break;
}

return str;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


int value;
int digit;

cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> value;


while (value > 0 )
{
    digit = value % 10;
    value = value / 10;
    cout << numString(value) << endl;


}
return 0;
}
```

My program is supposed to prompt the user for an integer value read that value, and output the word equivalent of each digit
For example if "9502" was entered it would output "NINE FIVE ZERO TWO"
Yet mine only outputs "NINE ZERO" and then stops. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cout << numString(value) << endl;` I guess you mean `cout << numString(digit) << endl;` here.

Comment: This helped a lot, and it prints the correct numbers. Except now it prints them backwards
like it prints TWO ZERO FIVE NINE

Comment: Yeah, you loop logic is "backwards". I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Hint: if you move the `while` loop logic to another function, you can use recursion to process/output `value` before outputting `numString(digit)`.

Answer (score 5):

> Yet mine only outputs "NINE ZERO" and then stops.

That's literally what you told it to do!

```
while (value > 0 )
```

You'll have to find some other way to signal a "termination" condition if zero is supposed to be valid.

Traditionally we let the system's own end-of-file signalling take care of that for us, so that we don't have to "reserve" some otherwise-valid input and use it as a signal flag.

```
while (cin >> value) {
    digit = value % 10;
    value = value / 10;
    cout << numString(value) << endl;
}
```

That fixes your loop, although unfortunately your maths are still wrong and your output is not what you intend. In fact, your `digit` variable is not used at all. I am not going to spoonfeed an algorithm here: you'll have to work out on paper how to achieve the business logic. :)

Comment: "thats literally what you told it to do." not really helpful

Comment: still not spot on. Will still not print anything else

Comment: Going to let the OP fix their algorithm. I'm fixing the "program stops early" problem as specified because that's nice and technical.

Comment: changed to +1 and removed mine since it was merged sort of, + yours was first

Comment: @Creris It actually was my downvote on your answer, along with this comment: _"Basing the essence of your answer on another one available isn't really productive. Think about editing in additional information, if you think that's necessary."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ at the time mine wasnt based on that one, since it explained completly different problem. But yes, could've pointed it out in here instead

Answer (score 1):

This is an analysis of your program using the input 9502.

### Iteration 1, in main:

(new) `value = 9502 / 10;`
(new) `digit = 9502 % 10;`
value == 950;
digit == 2;
call numString(**950**);
// Note: there is no case for 950 in numString so an empty string is returned.

### Iteration 2, in main:

(new) `value = 950 / 10;`
(new) `digit = 950 %  2;`
value == 95;
digit == 0;
call numString(**95**);
// Note: there is no case for 95 in numString so an empty string is returned.

The above iterations and variable values can be obtained with pen & paper (or a note pad).  You can also do the same with something called a *debugger*.

I hope this helps.